# Make a print method with for loop Java

Tags: java

The task of exercise is to make a method that will work like in Example.( We must use for loop. But if you know how to do it in another way, it will be also very interesting.) Input number can be any.

**Example:**
**Input:** *3*
**Output:**

```
**1** 
*121*  
12321
*121*
**1**
```

My example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    printMatrix(5);


}
public static void printMatrix (int n) {

    int d = n +(n-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <=d; j++){
            int abs = Math.abs(j-n);
            System.out.print(abs>i ? "*" : i-abs+1);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

My output:

```
****1****
***121***
**12321**
*1234321* 
123454321
```

I can't make the next step, to turn it upside down. Dose anybody hava an ideas?

Comment: Yes? And? Any question?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: -1 for not doing your assignment and get some other people do it for you.

Comment: Atleast provide some basics done by you, and a hint that this is an assignment

Comment: `while(true); System.out.println("**1**\n*121*\n12321\n*121*\n**1**");` Valid for all values of 3.

Comment: Sorry, that was bad post. I have made some edit in it. Waiting for some ideas=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have solved this exercise, but I think it is not a perfect solution. Does anybody have another way to solve this task?**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        printMatrix(5);


    }
    public static void printMatrix (int n) {

        int d = n +(n-1);
        int k = n*2;
        int g = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < d ; i++)
        {
            if(i<n){
                g++;
            }
            else{k=n*2;
                g--;}

            for(int j = 1; j <=d; j++){
                if (i < n){
                int abs = Math.abs(j-n);
                System.out.print(abs>i ? "*" : i-abs+1);
                }
                else{
                    k--;
                    int abs = Math.abs(k-n);
                    System.out.print(abs>g ? "*" : g-abs+1);

                }

            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
****1****
***121***
**12321**
*1234321*
123454321
*1234321*
**12321**
***121***
****1****
```